# how can I force listener to show path to listener.log in txt format in 'Listener Log File' field

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, listener

how can I force oracle 11g listener to show path to listener.log in txt format not log.xml in 'Listener Log File' field when displaying listener status?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
oracle@esmd:~> lsnrctl

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on 17-JAN-2020 09:05:51

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Welcome to LSNRCTL, type "help" for information.

LSNRCTL> show trc_directory
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=yyyy.xxx.zzz)(PORT=1521)))
LISTENER parameter "trc_directory" set to /oracle/diag/tnslsnr/esmd/listener/trace
The command completed successfully

LSNRCTL> exit
oracle@esmd:~> ls -l  /oracle/diag/tnslsnr/esmd/listener/trace
total 1112632
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 1138215020 2020-01-17 09:07 listener.log
oracle@esmd:~>



[oracle@yyyyyyyy ~]$ lsnrctl

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on 17-JAN-2020 06:14:37

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Welcome to LSNRCTL, type "help" for information.
LSNRCTL> show trc_dir
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=yyyyyyyyyyyy)(PORT=1521)))
LISTENER parameter "trc_directory" set to /opt/ora/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/yyyyyyyyyyyy/listener/trace
The command completed successfully
LSNRCTL> exit
[oracle@yyyyyyyyyyy ~]$ ls -l /opt/ora/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/yyyyyyyyyyy/listener/trace
total 341740
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 349654982 Jan 17 06:15 listener.log
[oracle@yyyyyyyyyyy ~]$
```

Comment: thanks for reply but what i would like to say is how can I force listener to show path to listener.log in txt format in 'Listener Log File' field in stead of log.xml ? 
Actually i when i execute lsnrtcl status , it is showing me :

LISTENER parameter     XXX\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File      XXX\network\log\listener.log

and for another listener i have

LISTENER parameter     XXX\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File      YYY\diag\tnslsnr\ZZZ\listener\alert\log.xml


thanks for reply